# Pointing second cursor to same database in sqlite on android, this a no no?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have this function that is filling out a class based on data from several tables.  I got the first cursor:

```
String query="SELECT * FROM SESSION where _id =" + mSessionID + ";";
Cursor c = dbAdapter.selectRecordsFromDB(query, null);
Session session=null;
c.moveToFirst();
```

This works great.  Then  a little lower I do this:

```
long galleryId = c.getInt(4);               
long packageId = c.getInt(5);
long contractId = c.getInt(6);

String query2="SELECT * FROM PHOTOPACKAGES WHERE _id =" + packageId + ";";
Cursor p = dbAdapter.selectRecordsFromDB(query2, null);
```

and the p cursor always returns -1 for its count.  I can go right into the sqlite in the adb and run the same query where packageId = 1 and it works great...so not sure why this is not working, i don't see any other errors...can you just not use two cursors on the same database? p.s. selectRecordsFromDB is a helper function:

```
    public Cursor selectRecordsFromDB(String query, String[] selectionArgs) {

    Cursor c = myDataBase.rawQuery(query, selectionArgs);
    return myDataBase.rawQuery(query, selectionArgs);       
}
```

Comment: Does anything DB related occur out side of what you gave here (perhaps prematurely calling a close to the DB)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your actual question: Yes you can target the same DB with multiple cursors. I believe there is something else wrong with your code. 
Also as Philip pointed out, creating Cursors is very costly and you do not want to make extras just because, and always close them when finished with them.

Comment: I always have a problem closing the cursors that my cursoradapters point to.  Am I missing something here?  Also with the above question, I have actually recoded it slightly and did an inner join, it seemed to fix my issue for now, still not sure what caused the second cursor just not working...

Answer (score 1):

Your selectRecordsFromDB function looks pretty darned weird, but it will probably work after a fashion, because the first cursor that you create goes out of focus straight away. Leaking open cursors like that is not a good idea though.

Comment: Thanks.  I am not closing my cursors cause in my list view I had an issue when I did..the list would go away so I just thought they had to work this way.  I will say I know therebis a rewrite in my future was my first stab at databases etc on the android.

Comment: Actually re-reading this, whats the proper way to not leak the cursors?  and do I have to keep the cursors around if I am using a SimpleCursorAdapter?